# What is meant by 'APT News'?

Tags: apt, 22.04

When I run `apt update` and `apt upgrade` on my system, I get this message:

```
 News about significant security updates, features and services will    
 appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
 Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
```

What is meant by 'APT News' ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is another example of Canonical adding their ["advertising stuff"](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/10/ubuntu-pro-terminal-ad) to terminal commands.

I believe that by 'APT News', they are simply referring to their own infomercials in the `apt` output (so it's a meta-reference so to speak).

Running this command will disable that output: (`sudo` might be needed)

```
sudo pro config set apt_news=false
```

For manual configuration, this command writes to the file `/etc/ubuntu-advantage/uaclient.conf`. This is an example config file:

```
# Ubuntu Pro client config file.
# If you modify this file, run "pro refresh config" to ensure changes are
# picked up by Ubuntu Pro client.

contract_url: https://contracts.canonical.com
daemon_log_file: /var/log/ubuntu-advantage-daemon.log
data_dir: /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage
log_file: /var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log
log_level: debug
security_url: https://ubuntu.com/security
timer_log_file: /var/log/ubuntu-advantage-timer.log
ua_config:
  apt_http_proxy: null
  apt_https_proxy: null
  apt_news: false
  global_apt_http_proxy: null
  global_apt_https_proxy: null
  http_proxy: null
  https_proxy: null
  metering_timer: 14400
  ua_apt_http_proxy: null
  ua_apt_https_proxy: null
  update_messaging_timer: 21600
  update_status_timer: 43200
```

So if you edit this file, be sure to run this command afterwards:

```
sudo pro refresh config
```

Comment: i think their are correct, this is a bit confusing or unhelpful.

Comment: It works! I had to use "sudo" when not running this command as root user.

Comment: What file does this command change? I'm looking for a way to manage this on a whole set of servers using a configuration management tool (Ansible).