# What are the services 'apt-news' and 'esm-cache', and how do I disable them?

Tags: apt, esm, ubuntu-pro

Recently, I've noticed that when I run `sudo apt update`, an extra 6 lines are written to my syslog each time:

```
Jan 29 21:17:01 xb systemd[1]: Starting Update APT News...
Jan 29 21:17:01 xb systemd[1]: Starting Update the local ESM caches...
Jan 29 21:17:02 xb systemd[1]: apt-news.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 29 21:17:02 xb systemd[1]: Finished Update APT News.
Jan 29 21:17:02 xb systemd[1]: esm-cache.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 29 21:17:02 xb systemd[1]: Finished Update the local ESM caches.
```

In addition, I can see that `apt-news.service` and `esm-cache.service` are both dated 2023-01-19, which means they're relatively new services introduced on my system.

I believe that these services are making noise in my syslog, and aren't really needed for my machine. So how can they be disabled so they don't trigger each time you use `apt update`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's explore the service files to see what info is available:

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/apt-news.service
[Unit]
Description=Update APT News

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt_news.py

$ cat /lib/systemd/system/esm-cache.service
# The ESM apt cache will maintain information about what ESM updates are
# available to a system. This information will be presented to users in the apt
# output, or when running pro security-status. These caches are maintained
# entirely outside the system apt configuration to avoid interference with user
# definitions. This service updates those caches. This will only have effect
# on releases where ESM is applicable, starting from Xenial: esm-apps for
# every LTS, and esm-infra for systems in expanded support period after the LTS
# expires.

[Unit]
Description=Update the local ESM caches

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/esm_cache.py
```

The `esm-cache.service` is a little more generous with information about its purpose, while the `apt-news.service` don't really clarify much. However, ['APT News'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441035/what-is-meant-by-apt-news/) was mentioned recently in another question, and one can conclude that it's connected to this `apt` prompt.

Inspecting the `apt` history further, it seems these services were installed with `ubuntu-advantage-tools` version 27.13.X. *(For me, this was rolled out with version 27.13.1 on 2023-01-27 for `arm64` and with version 27.13.2 on 2023-01-29 for `x64`.)*

Since these services seem to only provide additional information in connection to running `apt` (and `pro security-status`), they should be safe to disable.

This is done by simply masking the service units from `systemd`, like this:

```
$ sudo systemctl mask apt-news.service
$ sudo systemctl mask esm-cache.service
```

In addition, you can disable the entire `apt` ESM hook by doing the following: *(Thanks Daniel T)*

```
$ sudo dpkg-divert --rename --divert /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf.disabled --add /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf
```

*(Please note that the `--rename` option can be omitted on Ubuntu 22.04 and later, since this is now the default.)*

By moving this file, the entire `apt` ESM hook is disabled and will never run. The `dpkg-divert` will ensure that this file will always be redirected, even when `ubuntu-advantage-tools` are upgraded and tries to install the file again.

Comment: Looks like these services are seen only by Ubuntu Pro subscribers.

Comment: For noobs, 'mask' will be better than 'disbale' as disable can be re-activated anytime by  another process. Masked units need to be 'unmasked' before they can be reactivated.

Comment: `dpkg-divert` might be safer than moving the file in `/etc/apt` in ensuring the file is not recreated

Comment: @DanielT Answer now updated using `dpkg-divert`. 