# Console welcome message is no longer updating

Tags: command-line, apt, 22.04

After logging into Ubuntu 22.04 via SSH, the usual welcome message does not refresh itself any longer and I don't know why this happens. In addition to that I get the following error message when running `sudo apt update` :

```
Failed to start apt-news.service: Unit apt-news.service not found.  
Failed to start esm-cache.service: Unit esm-cache.service not found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution (to remove the message on `sudo apt update`) is to disable the `apt` ESM hook completely:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf.disabled
```

Also, [see this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452519/what-are-the-services-apt-news-and-esm-cache-and-how-do-i-disable-them).

Answer (score 8):

Solution:
`sudo apt install ubuntu-advantage-tools`