# Inhibit ESM messages at login

Tags: 20.04, login, motd, esm

I would like to inhibit the generation of the following messages when I ssh into my machine

```
Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates.
See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status
```

For some reason (I do not care to speculate why) these messages are not emitted through the normal motd process, but seem to emanate from `update-notifier`. There are scripts in the motd directory that appear to generate these messages, but removing them has no effect.

How can I prevent my system from generating these messages at login?

Comment: Maybe this way https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452519/what-are-the-services-apt-news-and-esm-cache-and-how-do-i-disable-them

Comment: @nobody thanks, but I already disabled the 'esm-hook'.

Comment: `sudo chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available`

Comment: Wouldn't that completely disable update-notifier?

Comment: I do not use update-notifier. Another way is to create empty file `$HOME/.hushlogin` But this will disable all motd. Oh ssh maybe this is https://serverfault.com/questions/36421/stop-ssh-login-from-printing-motd-from-the-client  helpful.

Comment: @nobody disabling update-notifier may be the best approach. If you write that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

These messages are defined in `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py` with no flags to disable them.

Here's a sed command that will neuter the functions that generate the messages by inserting a `return` statement as the first line of the message function:

```
sudo sed -Ezi.orig \
  -e 's/(def _output_esm_service_status.outstream, have_esm_service, service_type.:\n)/\1    return\n/' \
  -e 's/(def _output_esm_package_alert.*?\n.*?\n.:\n)/\1    return\n/' \
  /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py
```

A diff of the old and new files looks like this:

```
$ diff -u /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py{.orig,}
--- /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py.orig  2023-02-22 11:33:39.476095290 -0500
+++ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py   2023-02-22 11:59:41.396527682 -0500
@@ -160,6 +160,7 @@
 def _output_esm_package_alert(
     outstream, service_type, disabled_pkg_count, is_esm=False
 ):
+    return
     " output the number of upgradable packages if esm service was enabled "
     outstream.write("\n")
     if disabled_pkg_count > 0:
@@ -206,6 +207,7 @@
 
 
 def _output_esm_service_status(outstream, have_esm_service, service_type):
+    return
     if have_esm_service:
         outstream.write(gettext.dgettext("update-notifier",
                                          "Expanded Security Maintenance for "
```

Test the fix with this command:

```
$ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py --human-readable
1 update can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
```

Regenerate the cached message file

```
sudo /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available --force
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: And Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Is there an advantage to using ` /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py --human-readable ` vs ` sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/ ` to test the patch?

Comment: Interestingly, after apply the fix above, testing with `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py --human-readable` gives the desired output, while testing with `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` gives the output with ESM junk. Unfortunately I still get the ESM junk on login, which suggests the latter is the better test... :/

Comment: @rednoyz Just throwing my notes in here: the `run-parts` command runs teh scripts in that folder, and those scripts really just paste out a text file that's been generated before. I believe if you use jwatson0's last line for regenerating the cached message, that the `run-parts` command, and your login, will work correctly.

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way I found to avoid this esm message is to comment out the esm-repo in

`/var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.list`

```
# Written by ubuntu-advantage-tools

#deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security main
# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security main

#deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates main
# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates main
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. works perfectly

Comment: @taiyodayo I don't have that repo (or even the /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm directory), so this should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble which ubuntu release? Only tested in jammy.

Comment: @nobody that's a great point. I have 20.04 but I never said that. I'll add the tag. And have an upvote.

Comment: confirmed this working on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. maybe it is different in older point releases? In that case it is probably advisable to upgrade 20.04 to the latest version.

Comment: @taiyodayo I am running 20.04.6. But I have been removing ubuntu advantage's whack-a-mole installs since they started appearing, so maybe that's why I don't have the directories.

Comment: Weird.  I'm also running 22.04 LTS jammy, and the /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage directory exists but is empty.  I'm still getting the advertisement spam in the generated MOTD.

Comment: @TiStrga fresh install or upgrade. (mine is an upgrated release since 19.04)

Comment: @nobody Ours are semi-fresh installs.  More specifically, they're Canonical's official "pre-configured" images for AWS EC2, but "always have been 22.04 rather than upgraded from earlier LTS," if that's what you mean.  Maybe that's the crucial difference?

Comment: I reverted my changes in the file I mentioned. And get the esm message back. But I have a simple desktop install no  AWS image or something similiar. This could be the difference.

Comment: Didn't work for me on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 5):

Using e.g. bash:
create .hushlogin and
add something like this to an init file like .bashrc_profile

```
 grep 'immediately' /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
 grep 'security' /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
 grep 'upgradable' /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
 /etc/update-motd.d/98-reboot-required
```

On login:

```
2 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
*** System restart required ***
```

Note that /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available may be mode 0600 so you'll have to fix that.

Comment: This looks like a valid approach so +1. I ended up just disabling update-notifier and wrote my own script that runs at login and shows the number of updates.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: would you please post that script either here or somewhere else?

Comment: @bvargo I posted it in answer to another question, and a smarter user than me pointed out that it was wrong. So now I use the method in the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 1):

[Finished product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at8wX.png)

Another way to do it:

```
cd /etc/update-motd.d/
```

`rm 50-motd-news  91-contract-ua-esm-status`

```
nano /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
```

So that only

```
  0 updates can be applied immediately.
```

(One blank line on top, two spaces before '0')

```
nano 10-help-text
```

comment out

```
#printf "\n"[enter image description here][1]
#printf " * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com\n"
#printf " * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com\n"
#printf " * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage\n"
```

Comment: Instead of deleting the `/etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news` script entirely, you can also just edit `/etc/defaults/motd-news` to set `ENABLE=0`.