# message when connecting to a VPS

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-pro

When connecting to a VPS, it gives me a message:

```
Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates.
See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status
```

As I understand it, this message is related to ubuntu pro. But how can it be removed without crutches? And what does it have to do with exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inhibit ESM messages at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453749/inhibit-esm-messages-at-login)

Comment: Removed without using crutches? What does this refer to?