# All Ubuntu Pro security updates are listed in update-manager, can this be disabled?

Tags: 22.04, update-manager, ubuntu-pro

After the last update of `update-manager` it now shows a long list of "Ubuntu Pro" updates which I may install after enabling it in the settings.

As I am not in the target customer group for Pro, I would like to disable the display of updates which I cannot install anyway. Can this be done?

I tried the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434762/367444) provided for a similar question, but it has no effect.

NOTE: following the advice in https://askubuntu.com/a/1454914/367444 indeed gets rid of the advertised updates as I require.

Though my question is about the `update-manager` not about ESM messages as login, so I am not sure this question counts as a duplicate. It is a different question which happens to have the same answer as this other question. Whether closing as duplicate or leaving it open is better for future searches I don't know.

Comment: Does `sudo pro config set apt_news=false` work? Found https://canonical-ubuntu-pro-client.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/docs/howtoguides/disable_enable_apt_news/  here.

Comment: @nobody Remains to be seen for me. After running the command, `Software & Updates` still shows the `Ubuntu Pro` tab so I'm not yet convinced. I saw a comment by @TomasWard indicating that he will raise the issue with Canonical in 2024.

Comment: Do you have the file `/var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.list ` on your system?

Comment: @nobody yes, that file is present on my 22.04 system

Comment: Please comment the lines with deb out. I have not the update-manager on my system; so I do not know if this is enough in this case.

Comment: OK commented out the deb lines in the file `ubuntu-esm-apps.list` but tab still remains so will have to wait for next update notification to see if still present

Comment: @nobody looks promising - I forced an update using `Software Updater` and the message was not presented... I think you could post that as an answer for now...

Comment: In that case it is a dupe to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453749/inhibit-esm-messages-at-login/1454914#1454914

Comment: ah thanks - I looked for a dupe but couldn't find a suitable one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inhibit ESM messages at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453749/inhibit-esm-messages-at-login)

Comment: If you are planning to ignore security updates, then reconsider having a lot of that software installed in the first place. Uninstalling those packages will also eliminate those notifications.