# Ubuntu pro subscription is not updating esm-apps

Tags: ubuntu-pro

I keep get invited to opt in to esm-apps because I have apps which have updates. But I have subscribed.
Ubuntu 22.04

Each time I get this:

```
 [~/blog] [] $ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  imagemagick libavcodec-extra libopusfile0 libjs-jquery-ui
  libmaven3-core-java libavdevice58 ffmpeg libopenexr25 libpostproc55
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libavcodec-extra58
  libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16 libswscale5 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
  libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common libavformat58 libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
```

But I set up Ubuntu Pro a long time ago.

```
$ sudo pro status
WARNING:root:failed to process /proc/version_signature.
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
esm-apps         yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
realtime-kernel  yes       disabled  Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated

Enable services with: pro enable <service>

     Account: landscape@gr...
Subscription: Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the services 'apt-news' and 'esm-cache', and how do I disable them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452519/what-are-the-services-apt-news-and-esm-cache-and-how-do-i-disable-them)

Comment: I think this messages pops up no matter what. See the above answer to disable this.

Comment: I think you may be right. The apps in questions have actually been updated to the esm version