# APT Command fails. Can't apt update and apt-get install packages

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 22.04, update-manager

Running on `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS jammy` running on `aarch64`

My `etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this https://pastebin.com/MDYEWzmi
The issue started after I couldnt install few packages for canvas and I modified the sources.list file, since then, I tried many different versions of the files to resolve this issue but all failed.

The output when I run `sudo apt update`

```
Failed to start apt-news.service: Unit apt-news.service not found.
Failed to start esm-cache.service: Unit esm-cache.service not found.
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:2 http://eu-paris-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
## MORE LINES ##
Err:55 http://eu-paris-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.122 80]
Err:73 http://eu-paris-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.122 80]
Fetched 607 kB in 5s (126 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://eu-paris-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.122 80]E: Failed to fetch http://eu-paris-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.122 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://eu-paris-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.122 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Full version because askubuntu marks the full one as spam https://pastebin.com/EjmTzLy8

The output when I run `sudo apt-get install <package>`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package autoconf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
```

The output when I run `sudo apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Network: I am using an Oracle Cloud Instance, no changes were made on the firewall before the issue appeared, I can ping [91.189.91.122] despite it saying 404 Not Found, I run a test to see if network still go through by running the command `wget http://eu-paris-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/autoconf/autoconf_2.71.orig.tar.gz`, the file was downloaded successfully

Comment: @user535733 But I can ping and resolve the domain just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check below URL http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/ you do not have `binary-arm64/Packages` listed.

And same goes for other URLs http://eu-paris-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/ and backports.

So Please fix those source URLs.

And you dont have to worry about apt-new and esm-cache, more info can be found here : [What are the services 'apt-news' and 'esm-cache', and how do I disable them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452519/what-are-the-services-apt-news-and-esm-cache-and-how-do-i-disable-them)

May be you should fix your source because autoconf is part of main, if your source list cant get main package metadata, try changing to another mirror.