# Update/upgrade issues,ESM,Desktop version, slow ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, updates, .desktop, esm, ubuntu-pro

I run a node on the desktop version of Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. In the terminal, I perform updates and upgrades using the apt command. After that, I received additional updates for Ubuntu PRO. However, after the last update, my apps have become slow, slow like computer is 10+ yrs old.
Also it runs 24/7(node) and it has very fast response on all apps.

I have come across some solutions, but none of them seem to be applicable to the desktop version. I am unsure if everything runs smoothly on the desktop version with ESM/Ubuntu PRO.(python 2.7 ?)

[ESM/Ubunto Pro updates offered to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ljjy.png)

As I am not an experienced Linux user, any help would be appreciated. These are similar issues that I have already encountered here;

[What are the services 'apt-news' and 'esm-cache', and how do I disable them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452519/what-are-the-services-apt-news-and-esm-cache-and-how-do-i-disable-them)

[What are ESM Apps, and how do they relate to Ubuntu Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452497/what-are-esm-apps-and-how-do-they-relate-to-ubuntu-pro)

I have solid configuration when we are talking about hardware; i7-10700K, 32GB RAM, 1TB NvME,NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070, 1Gbit internet provider connection so i think that is not hardware issue. I don't know why they are pushing Ubuntu PRO updates, but when we are talking about python mine current version is 3.9.12, don't know why they are pushing 2.7 With Stacer application i see that some CPU % is taken by node and it is little more then usual, about 30%

I do not know what to do next.

free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       7,3Gi        12Gi       223Mi        11Gi        23Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi       659Mi       1,4Gi
```

Comment: "*My apps have become slow*". What diagnostic actions have you taken? Or are you asking how to diagnose? It-must-be-due-to-an-update is rarely true, so be open to other causes that your investigation may discover. The #1 cause of a "slow" system is swapping due to too little RAM for the activities you are asking the system to handle.

Comment: Like i said before i am not exp Ubuntu user, and question still stands.After upgrade over terminal, Ubuntu run slow(before that was "flying").I believe that with that update come some other unnecessary updates(it offers me Ubuntu Pro  with python 2.7?) which probably suffocates Ubuntu to run proprely.
If you have any idea how to test please write me down. Thanks

Comment: During "slow", open a terminal and run `free -h`. Copy the complete output into your question above.