# How to get rid of message in apt: "An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed ..."

Tags: 22.04

When I do "sudo apt upgrade" I always get in turn the message. It is really getting annoying.

```
An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed with USN-6188-1 & 6119-1:
CVE-2023-2650: possible DoS translating ASN.1 object identifiers.
Ensure you have updated the package to its latest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

From the output it looks than nothing must be upgraded, so how should I make sure to update my packages, and what packages should I update?

Comment: Also possibly this: [What is meant by 'APT News'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441035/what-is-meant-by-apt-news/). In short, it's Canonical's "marketing fluff" that has been added to the upgrade prompts. Luckily, it can be disabled.

Comment: Finally, this isn't a warning, just a service message. If you do security upgrades regularly, you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: @ArturMeinild should i wait with this this isn't a serious problem right?

Comment: This message in itself does not indicate a problem. Only if your package `openssl` isn't updated is it a problem - and I see no indication of a problem here (or in your other question for that matter).

Comment: @ArturMeinild, I disabled APT news by running command sudo pro config set apt_news=false and it works!