# sudo apt upgrade message: The following packages have been kept back (...)

Tags: apt, libreoffice, openssl

I ran sudo apt upgrade today at my machine i got these weird messages?

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed with USN-6188-1 & 6119-1:
# CVE-2023-2650: possible DoS translating ASN.1 object identifiers.
# Ensure you have updated the package to its latest version.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  fonts-opensymbol libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common
  libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3
  libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za
  libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary
  libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-writer libuno-cppu3
  libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3
  libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 python3-uno ufw uno-libs-private ure
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

My first question is that with OpenSSL message should i do something about that?
My second question should i wait with the libreoffice packages because they are being held back?

Comment: For the first part of your question, see [the exact same question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480859/how-to-get-rid-of-message-in-apt-an-openssl-vulnerability-has-recently-been-fi) (which means you can effectively leave it out, and focus only on the held back packages).

Comment: For `ufw`, it's currently in ["phased updates"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them). I don't know why LibreOffice is held back.

Comment: @ArturMeinild phased out does it mean i should some days before i take any action i tried sudo apt full-upgrade but that didn't work?

Comment: Yes it's described in the phased updates post I linked to. It will install eventually (after a number of days).

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks :)! Is the same with the Open SSL error message?

Comment: I replied in the other thread. 