# Help with microcode update message and a package on Ubuntu Server that have been kept back

Tags: apt, server, package-management, upgrade, updates

I tried to update my Ubuntu Server(s) `22.04.3 LTS` a while ago and it gives me the following message. What exactly does it mean? Why it kept `sosreport` back and what should I do?

```
Last login: Fri Oct 20 14:41:03 2023 from 192.168.***.***
***@***:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for ***:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# Canonical released microcode updates for both Intel (CVE-2022-40982) and AMD
# (CVE-2023-20593). ‘Unattended upgrades’ provide security updates by default.
# Ensure it remains enabled to always get all updates as they become available.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  sosreport
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it I suspect Phased Updates.

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade sosrepot` and `sudo apt-get install sosrepot` from this answer `https://askubuntu.com/a/602/578979` of the link you gave me, one on each Ubuntu Server machine I have and the package upgraded on both!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Running `apt policy sosreport` reveals this is phased updates. Also, it's unrelated to the info message about microcode.

Comment: @ArturMeinild do I have to do something with this info message about microcode?

Comment: [No](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441035/what-is-meant-by-apt-news).